# sed with multiple conditions

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I'd like to have your kind help on the matter of using `sed` command for searching/replacing the text in file with some specific purposes below.

Supposing I'm having `/tmp/foo` with following content.

```
aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2 KEYWORD_1 KEYWORD_2
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

The return should have as following:

1. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2` >>> replace line to `Hello World`

```
Hello World
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2 KEYWORD_1 KEYWORD_2
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

2. find /tmp/foo which lines begins with `aaa` >>> replace line to `Hello World`

```
Hello World
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
Hello World
Hello World
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

3. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace line to `Hello World`

```
Hello World
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
Hello World
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

4. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` at beginning AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace line to `Hello World`

```
Hello World
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
Hello World
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

5. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace `KEYWORD_1` to `NEW_TEXT` only

```
aaa whatever_a1 NEW_TEXT whatever_a2
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2 NEW_TEXT KEYWORD_2
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

6. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> purge `KEYWORD_1` text only

```
aaa whatever_a1  whatever_a2
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2  KEYWORD_2
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

7. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace string behind `KEYWORD_1` to `Hello World` only (keep `KEYWORD_1` in line)

```
aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 Hello World
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2 KEYWORD_1 Hello World
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

8. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace string front of KEYWORD_1 to `Hello World` only (keep `KEYWORD_1` in line)

```
Hello World KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
Hello World KEYWORD_1 KEYWORD_2
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

9. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace string behind `KEYWORD_1` to `Hello World` only (including `KEYWORD_1` text)

```
aaa whatever_a1 Hello World
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2 Hello World
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

10. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` >>> replace string front of `KEYWORD_1` to `Hello World` only (including KEYWORD_1 text)

```
Hello World whatever_a2
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
Hello World KEYWORD_2
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

11. find /tmp/foo which lines contains `aaa` AND `KEYWORD_1` AND `KEYWORD_2` >>> replace line to `Hello World`

```
aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2
bbb whatever_b1 whatever_b2
ccc whatever_c1 whatever_c2 KEYWORD_1 whatever_c3
aaa whatever_aaa1 whatever_aaa2
Hello World
ddd whatever_d1 whatever_d2 KEYWORD_1
```

Thanks a lot,

Cuong

Comment: You can read the manual of `sed`.

Comment: Sorry but I tried none of above yet, also the questions are involved in the first of each 11 case. My bad when not marking the question mark in those 11 cases.

Comment: We're not going to throw code at you, so please show your attempts and research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be happier with awk, e.g.:

1. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2 >>> replace line to Hello World

   ```
   awk '/aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2/ { $0 = "Hello World" } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
2. find /tmp/foo which lines begins with aaa >>> replace line to Hello World

   ```
   awk '/^aaa/ { $0 = "Hello World" } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
3. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace line to Hello World

   ```
   awk '/aaa/ && /KEYWORD_1/ { $0 = "Hello World" } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
4. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa at beginning AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace line to Hello World

   ```
   awk '/^aaa/ && /KEYWORD_1/ { $0 = "Hello World" } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
5. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace KEYWORD_1 to NEW_TEXT only

   ```
   awk '/aaa/ { sub(/KEYWORD_1/,"NEW_TEXT") } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
6. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> purge KEYWORD_1 text only

   ```
   awk '/aaa/ { sub(/KEYWORD_1/,"") } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
7. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace string behind KEYWORD_1 to Hello World only (keep KEYWORD_1 in line)

   ```
   awk '/aaa/ { sub(/KEYWORD_1.*/,"KEYWORD_1 Hello World") } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
8. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace string front of KEYWORD_1 to Hello World only (keep KEYWORD_1 in line)

   ```
   awk '/aaa/ { sub(/.*KEYWORD_1/,"Hello World KEYWORD_1") } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
9. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace string behind KEYWORD_1 to Hello World only (including KEYWORD_1 text)

   ```
   awk '/aaa/ { sub(/KEYWORD_1.*/,"Hello World") } 1' /tmp/foo
   ```
10. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 >>> replace string front of KEYWORD_1 to Hello World only (including KEYWORD_1 text)

    ```
    awk '/aaa/ { sub(/.*KEYWORD_1/,"Hello World") } 1' /tmp/foo
    ```
11. find /tmp/foo which lines contains aaa AND KEYWORD_1 AND KEYWORD_2 >>> replace line to Hello World

    ```
    awk '/aaa/ && /KEYWORD_1/ && /KEYWORD_2/ { $0 = "Hello World" } 1' /tmp/foo
    ```

Note that if you don't like to repeat the searched key explicitly in the replacement text `sub(/KEYWORD.*/,"KEYWORD foo")` you can use GNU awk for `gensub()`: `$0=gensub(/(KEYWORD).*/,"\1 foo","")`. Also if you don't want to find/replace KEYWORD when it appears in the middle of another string, you can use GNU awk's `\<` and `\>` word delimiters around it to isolate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/aaa whatever_a1 KEYWORD_1 whatever_a2/Hello World/g' name_of_file.txt
```

(or whatever file format you have)... would do #1 then for specific changes on specific lines, simply do

```
sed -e '2s/from_this/to_this/'
```

where the 2 would mean at line 2, or a 5 would mean at line 5, etc.
Sed can give rise to some very powerful one-liners.

Comment: Why the -1 on my answer?  It solves #1 for the OP, does not do all 11 questions (this is not a homework assignment), and shows the power of sed in changing a specific word(s) at a specific line.  I encourage the OP to post what he/she has attempted, where he/she got stuck, then ask for specific help when the problem was encountered (with the OP's code).

Comment: While it answers the question, the solution is incomplete. The regex should be anchored.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "regex should be anchored" and feel free to make any changes.

Comment: @Cuong Nguyen Viet: Dear OP, I would encourage you to google around first and attempt these problems (the Linux and Unix forums are very helpful) and perhaps return here with an edit of your question.

Comment: @XYZ927: Thanks for your help, I should do.